# Difference between Number of CPU cycles of a device and CPU frequency of a device

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

I am a researcher working upon task offloading among IOT devices. While programming for my work, I have come across two terms that is Number of CPU cycles of a device and CPU frequency of a device. I am not sure if they both are same or if there is any difference between them. Anyone with reference who could clarify that would be highly appreciated

Comment: A researcher could... search a bit more I'd say - there are tons of info about this on the web like this [one, on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652141/21215023)

Comment: @Sylvain I researched, but I was not sure if those answers are reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The terms CPU cycles and CPU frequency are related but not interchangeable.

The CPU frequency relates to the speed a CPU is working at. Simplisticly speaking its the number of things/calculations it **can do** a second)

CPU cycles us a measurement of the amount of work done.

An analogy would be -

CPU frequency would be analogous to the amount of water flowing through a tap  (or kW power draw in an electric circuit)

CPU cycles would equate to the size of container needed to catch the water (or kWh required to recharge a battery of a given size)

Comment: for instance you might say that a task required X cycles, and using the frequency calculate the execution time, or you might say that the task completed in X seconds, and from that calculate the cycles required (for an precise real number X). `F = CS, C = F/S, S = F/C`.

Answer (score 1):

Exerpted from
https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/gaming/resources/cpu-clock-speed.html

> ###### Clock speed is one of your CPU’s key specifications—but what does it really mean?
>
> The performance of your CPU—the “brain” of your PC—has a major impact on the speed at which programs load and how smoothly they run. However, there are a few different ways to measure processor performance. Clock speed (also “clock rate” or “frequency”) is one of the most significant.

> ###### What Is Clock Speed?
>
> In general, a higher clock speed means a faster CPU. However, many other factors come into play.
>
> Your CPU processes many instructions (low-level calculations like arithmetic) from different programs every second. The clock speed measures the number of cycles your CPU executes per second, measured in GHz (gigahertz).
>
> A “cycle” is technically a pulse synchronized by an internal oscillator, but for our purposes, they’re a basic unit that helps understand a CPU’s speed. During each cycle, billions of transistors within the processor open and close.
> [image]
> Frequency is more operations within a given amount of time, as represented above
>
> A CPU with a clock speed of 3.2 GHz executes 3.2 billion cycles per second. (Older CPUs had speeds measured in megahertz, or millions of cycles per second.)
>
> Sometimes, multiple instructions are completed in a single clock cycle; in other cases, one instruction might be handled over multiple clock cycles. Since different CPU designs handle instructions differently, it’s best to compare clock speeds within the same CPU brand and generation.
>
> For example, a CPU with a higher clock speed from five years ago might be outperformed by a new CPU with a lower clock speed, as the newer architecture deals with instructions more efficiently. An X-series Intel® processor might outperform a K-series processor with a higher clock speed, because it splits tasks between more cores and features a larger CPU cache. But within the same generation of CPUs, a processor with a higher clock speed will generally outperform a processor with a lower clock speed across many applications. This is why it’s important to compare processors from the same brand and generation.

> ###### Why Does Clock Speed Matter?
>
> CPU clock speed is a good indicator of your processor’s performance. Though applications like video editing and streaming are known to rely on multi-core performance, many new video games still benchmark best on CPUs with the highest clock speed.

#### Additional Resources

- Wikipedia: [CPU Clock Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_rate)
- Wikipedia: [CPU Instruction cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle)
- Wikipedia: [Central processing unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit)
- Wikipedia: [Dynamic frequency scaling (CPU throttling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling)